# What is the difference between using --save-exact and a package-lock.json file during npm install?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

In the docs for Prettier (a code formatter), they install it with the `--save-exact` flag ([1](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html)):

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier
```

Since I have never heard of this flag, I looked it up in the npm docs ([2](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install)):

> `-E, --save-exact`: Saved dependencies will be configured with an exact version rather than using npm's default semver range operator.

I can see why they want every developer using the same version. But why does this seem to require the `--save-exact` flag? As soon as `package.lock` file is committed, shouldn't this serve the same purpose?